# joining two tables with no unique identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

joining two tables with a name

i tried to concat the names in the other table as . on table1 its David john Smith and on table2 is David john and there is no unique identifier

```
select [RSA ID Number],a.Name,a.email,a.[Company Name],a.[start_date],a.Status 
from Sheet1$ as a join dbo.themba$ as e
on  ((e.Name like '%'+ a.name + '%' and a.Name like '%'+ e.Name + '%')
or (e.Name like concat('%', a.Name, '%')and a.Name like concat('%', e.Name, '%')) )  
or  e.Email=a.email
```

Comment: This does not say what query you want or what problem you have. Use enough words & sentences & references to parts of examples to be clear. [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You have used the AND operator where you need OR:

```
select [RSA ID Number], a.Name, a.email, a.[Company Name], a.[start_date],a.Status 
from Sheet1$ as a join dbo.themba$ as e
on  
  e.Name like concat('%', a.Name, '%') 
  or 
  a.Name like concat('%', e.Name, '%')  
  or  
  e.Email=a.email
```

You should qualify the column `[RSA ID Number]` with `a` or `e` (the alias of the table where it belongs).
Also be consistent when you do string concatenations. 
Use either the operator `+` or the function `concat()`, but not both.